# Does anyone know a docker image that contains The MySQL Test Framework, Version 2.0?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I need to deliver some SQL queries for a job application and those should go with test cases.

I created a Mysql container from the latest image but it doesn't contain the test framework. According to the Mysql website, the server can be downloaded with or without this framework. So I couldn't find an official image with this.

I've been looking for this image and I can't seem to find it. The search strings are "evil" and the results are not related to the subject.

I am not fluent in Docker nor Mysql.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you install it on a Linux system?

Comment: I thought the MySQL test framework was for testing that MySQL was operating as expected and not to test your code.

Comment: @NigelRen at least looking at the sample test cases it seems to be testing MySQL commands. See this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/writing-tests-controlling-information.html

Comment: @user2915097 install what?

Comment: Mysql test framework

Comment: @user2915097 it gets installed with MySQL if you download the complete package.

Comment: So it should be on hub.docker.com

Comment: @user2915097 Can you find it? I didn't!